# command to Substract two timestamps in unix

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp

I am writing a script and which requires to calculate the difference between the two timestamps . I have done some search but didn't get a clue so far.

For Example say:

```
time1 = 20160314 10:16:27
time2 = 20160313 15:17:28
```

From the above I need to get result like below: difference is: "**1 day 5 hours 1 minute 1 second**"

Please help me in resolving this.

Comment: btw time1 - time2 is 1 day minus 5h 1m 1s

Comment: Lol
is it a  command ? I would be so thankful if you are able to help

Comment: You'll need the `date` command (hint, `-d` option), and shell arithmetic (hint, `/` and `%` operators) to do your calculations.

Comment: @BhargavSutapalli - How do you calculate that difference between those two dates and times? Looks to me as if the difference is about 5 hours short of one day, not 5 hours more.

Answer (score 2):

```
datediff() {
    t1=$(date -d "$1" +%s)
    t2=$(date -d "$2" +%s)
    diff=$(( $t1 - $t2 ))

    echo "Duration: $(( $diff / 86400 )) days $(($diff / 3600 )) hours $((( $diff % 3600) / 60)) minutes $(( $diff % 60 )) seconds"
}
```

`date -d "$1" +%s` converts given date to time stamp(counted from 1970).

More details on date conversion

http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html#Date-input-formats

**example:**

```
$ date -d 2013-07-05 +%m/%d/%Y
07/05/2013
$ date -d 07/05/2013 +%F
2013-07-05
```

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24626/quickly-calculate-date-differences :-)

Answer (score 2):

The command you likely want to use is `date`, but its usage depends on your operating system. You've specified [unix](/questions/tagged/unix) in the tags on your question, which isn't really specific enough for a single answer.

In general though, you'll calculate differences between dates by counting the seconds between them. So your method should be to figure out the unix epoch second for each of your dates, subtract to find the difference, and then print the results in whatever format suits you.

In Linux, GNU date (from "coreutils") has a `-d` option that can understand a number of date references.

```
$ time1="20160314 10:16:27"
$ date -d "$time1" '+%s'
1457964987
```

And you can calculate the difference in seconds between two dates like this:

```
echo "$(( $(date -d "$time1" '+%s') - $(date -d "$time2" '+%s') ))"
```

Converting that to your output format is a simple matter of division and remainders:

```
s=$(( $(date -d "$time1" '+%s') - $(date -d "$time2" '+%s') ))

printf "%d day(s) %d hours %d minute %d second\n" \
   $(( s / 86400 )) \
   $(( s % 86400 / 3600 )) \
   $(( s % 3600 / 60 )) \
   $(( s % 60 ))
```

In FreeBSD, on the other hand, the `-d` option does something completely different, and you'd use `-f` and `-v` to parse and adjust a date.  For example:

```
$ time1="20160314 10:16:27"
$ date -j -f '%Y%m%d %T' "$time1" '+%s'
1457964987
```

Figuring out the difference looks similar to the Linux method then:

```
s=$(( $(date -j -f '%Y%m%d %T' "$time1" '+%s') - $(date -j -f '%Y%m%d %T' "$time2" '+%s') ))
```

You can then use the same `printf` command I've shown above to format your output.

I don't have details on how the `date` command works in Solaris or other operating systems, but you can `man date` from a shell to see if either of these strategies appears to be compatible with whatever operating system you're running.